# Enviar dados para paginas diferentes em um form

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Boa tarde pessoal, tenho um form que precisa fazer 2 acoes diferente, 1 deles é fazer um update em uma pagina php com nome update.php e outro para delete com nome delete.php, preciso que dependo da opção clicada o form envie para update ou delete, porem não sei como fazer, alguem pode ajudar?

Comment: Faz uma pagina onde faz as duas ações

Comment: Mas caso seja extremamente necessário, caso realmente não tenha como fazer as duas ações em uma unica pagina PHP, ai vc pode usar `$.ajax()` e enviar para as duas

Comment: Poste o código do seu form, para fazer isso, vc vai precisar usar javascript, jquery resolve perfeitamente seu problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode colocar um combo dentro do seu formulário e adicionar um evento dentro dele que pegue a opção selecionado e então mudar o action do formulario de acordo.

Tipo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: a chamada desse função pode ser realizado no evento onSubmit do formulário?